# Volume is too low and Affect to Windows

Tags: dual-boot, sound, alsa

Using sound-card that Xonar Phoebus, Installed 16.04 (Dual-boot w/ Windows)
I heard not anything from this soundcard but USB Speaker(JBL Pebbles) works.
then, I delete boot-loader and partition of Ubuntu, and re-installed Windows, and installed driver. but volume is too low even 100. is my sound-card broken?
before install Ubuntu, can hear well in 50%.

Comment: Did you completely power off the computer before running Windows again?

Comment: maybe reboot into windows and did bcdboot. is that cause?

Comment: boot 16.04 w/ Live USB, set to 100 CM8888(Headphone)'s volume then shutdown and boot Windows, can't fix...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just changed over to Ubuntu so not sure how to do that in Linux.

Since you have a copy of windows, go into the Device Manager and select the sound card device and un-install it. Then install again it and that should reset anything Ubuntu has changed.

Or, try going to the sound card website and downloading the driver again and install it manually in the Device Manager.

Comment: just tried re-install from device manager / Asus website. nothing has changed. and I didn't changed some audio settings in Ubuntu.